# Using ethernet connection for two completely different purposes

Tags: ethernet, nic

I have a Dell desktop machine with one ethernet port and one NIC.

I need to use ethernet connection for two completely different purposes.

1. One is to get internet access via LAN and read more stackoverflow.
2. The other is to talk to my FPGA eval board and send/receive data
   using ethernet.

Is having two NICs a good option, a splitter box externally connected or any other solutions for this kinds of usecases?

(I do not want to mess or change the configurations everytime I switch between internet to eval board with just one ethernet port on the system.(I am doing it currently))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is no problem.
The one you connect to internet typically use DHCP.
The other set it to static IP address with another subnet than the first one.
The FPGA also use static IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another solution I found that make me worry less about ethernet configuring on one port, is to use USB to ethernet adapter for the FPGA board, or for the internet access.